# What is this matrix notation and how is it solved?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, binomial-coefficients

I've never taken a stats class, or linear algebra or much of anything that involves matrices.  In one of my books they give me this as part of an example and it states,

> $$\binom{6}{4} = 15 \text{ combinations}$$

I don't understand how the math is done for that statement. I don't get where $15$ comes from. I'm assuming it is some sort of a probability formula, but I am not sure.

Comment: It's a binomial coefficient, read "6 choose 4," and it's defined as ${6\choose 4}=\frac{6!}{(6-4)!\cdot4!}$.

Comment: Yeah that's not actually a matrix, it's a combinatorics thing.  It means if you have six distinguishable things, how many ways can you pick four of them.

Comment: It is not a matrix, it is the standard notation  for a `binomial coefficient` and it reads as ‘6 choose 4’.

Comment: Perfect! That makes sense, the way the math is and the description @GregoryGrant gave fits into the example. That filled some gaps instantly. I checked out the Wiki page for `binomial coefficient` to see a couple of the proofs behind it.  Thanks guys, quick also!

Comment: @symplectomic: it is *not* ‘defined as’. What uou mention is formula to compute it. The definition is it's the coefficient of $x^4$ when you expand $(1+x)^6$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in some comments, the notation does not relate to matrices. It is a mathematical notation for the binomial coefficient. If you did not place an equal sign and a value on the right hand sice, it could be confused with a a matrix notation or a vector.

It appears in many contexts, one of them is to answer the question "in how many ways can you select r objects from n objects".

$$\binom{n}{r}$$

The calculation requires you to be familiar with the other notation of factorial:

$$n!=n*(n-1)*(n-2)...(3)*(2)*(1)$$

For example, $$6! = 6*5*4*3*2*1$$

Now the value of:

$$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$$

So the expression you have can be written as:

$$\binom{6}{4} = \frac{6!}{(6-4)!4!}=\frac{6*5*4*3*2*1}{(2*1)(4*3*2*1)}=15$$

For more information, see: [Combinations and Permutations](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html#Combinations).